# react-native ios Podfile issue with "use_native_modules!"

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

In my react-native project (react-native@0.60) in the ios/ dir I run `pod install` and get this error:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String.

 #  from /Users/coryrobinson/projects/hhs2/ios/Podfile:37
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    use_native_modules!
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I haven't added or changed anything in this Podfile - it's all react-native generated. (I'm not experienced in iOS dev so this might be a simple fix, I just don't know what to look for :-|) Thanks for any help!

Here is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'hhs2' do
  # Pods for hhs2
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'
  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'hhs2Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'hhs2-tvOS' do
  # Pods for hhs2-tvOS

  target 'hhs2-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Just delete Podfile.lock works. if you are facing issue even after all the answers.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here is the correct answer:

1 - Your `Podfile` should contain this line on top

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
```

2 - Make sure your `package.json` and `node_module` folders has this module installed

`cli-platform-ios/native_modules`

3 - If you didn't find after you run `yarn install` - means you have old cache node_modules in your machine and you need to clean it before reinstalling the package again.

4 - Clean cache `yarn cache clean`

**5 - Make sure you have this file `react-native.config.js` and its configuration is VALID - and it doesn't have non-existing NPM packages - this step is LAST AND MOSTLY THE CAUSE of the error**

Example of my `react-native.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/'],
  dependencies: {}, // make sure this dependencies are all valid installed packages or empty if you don't need it
};
```

6 - Install node packages `yarn install` and your pods should work now! `pod install --repo-update`

HAPPY coding!

Comment: Should react-native.config.js file be in root folder or in ios?

Comment: Also make sure your config file uses `require` rather than `import`. ESLint auto-fixes broke mine by swapping those out.

Comment: Also if you don't have `use_native_modules!` in your pod file it won't work, so add it in there.

Comment: I started with the error written above, followed @Meabed suggestions, and now I am getting '[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!.' for the 'use_native_modules!' line. Any idea why? I tried looking for this error in SO and cannot make any of the suggsted solutions to work.

Comment: @Yossi please share your pod file in gist.

Comment: @Meabed I decided to try and recreate the project. If I face the same problem I will post it here. Thanks!

Comment: FYI the module is called `@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios`, not `cli-platform-ios/native_modules`, in case anyone is trying to install it.

Answer (score 11):

Downgraded @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios from 3.1.0 to 3.0.0 and it worked.

Added

```
"@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "3.0.0"
```

to package.json.

Run npm install and then pod install to get it working again.

Comment: Works, as of March 2020

Comment: This got rid of the error, however now I get `Specifying multiple post_install hooks is unsupported` - any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, I've upgrade React Native version from v0.71.12 -> v0.72.5 and I was experiencing this problem. Your solution was the only one that worked.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using

```
pod install --project-directory=ios
```

you might need to tweak the Podfile by replacing

`use_native_modules!`

to

`use_native_modules!(".")`

Maybe this behavior will be improved in the future, I opened an issue about it https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/657

Comment: [!] Passing custom root to use_native_modules! is deprecated.
    - CLI detects root of the project automatically. The "" argument was ignored.

Comment: I had the opposite problem (if I understand you correctly) -- I get the the error if I (cd ios; pod install), but `pod install --project-directory=ios` works and I've used it for years. But I just tried a CI build on app center which assumes (cd ios; pod install) and it breaks. I've tried every fix in this question and nothing helps. (Except perhaps removing old RN packages that don't support cocoapods -- don't know how to identify those.)

Answer (score 6):

this is because the outdate yarn version on your device,
if you on macOS you can upgrade/install the yarn with follow this link:
[here it is](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#alternatives-stable)

**be aware** to delete `node-module` and `yarn.lock` file, install all packages again, navigate to *ios* folder and run `pod install`.

Answer (score 6):

Verify if you have  `@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios` in your *package.json*,

if you dont run:

`npm install @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios`

then

`cd ios && pod install`

Answer (score 3):

i just dropped the whole node_modules and RN cache folder and did a clean reinstall, this fixed the "use_native_modules" problem so far....but after that i had to hassle a lot with other libs which where just not RN0.60 ready ;)

Comment: where is the RN cache folder?

Answer (score 3):

For me, I deleted the `node_modules` and installed again by using `npm install` . After that, I navigated to `/ios` folder and ran `pod install` it worked.

Comment: Sharing some more details can be helpful, E.g where to find "node_modules"

Comment: @UmairAfzal  - Google `node_modules`. It is a folder in your project; a local cache of all npm packages your project uses. (I think it is created when you do `npm install`.) Every project that uses `npm` will have this as a sub-folder of the project's root folder.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, my guess is for most people, the accepted answer will fix their issue. For me, the fix was so bizarre, I had to add it here.

For whatever reason, I ended up creating an invalid `AndroidManifest.xml` file in my android native setup.

I looked at the full error output, and the first lines of the error referenced a line number and column number. At that point in my xml file I broke the xml formatting.

2 days of searching to find a GitHub Issue with a description of where to [look](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/846#issuecomment-554252621).

Comment: YEAH, same here... could not imagine how a broken AndroidManifest.xml could lead to  IOS podlike issue

Answer (score 2):

I too was having this very exact same issue and nothing here worked for me. In my particular case, I am using Nx monorepo tool and I had removed a package in my root level package.json, but forgot to correspondingly remove it from my Expo app package.json, so when I'd run *run-ios* target and it would try and build the pods, it'd fail for this reason (because symlinked package was missing). This might not be a solution for everyone, but if it'll save someone else 4 hours and a headache, why not post it

Answer (score 2):

Same issue appeared after upgrading react native from 0.65 to 0.71.
Running `pod install` got me this:

```
 #  from /Users/username/Documents/projectname/ios/Podfile:25
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  target 'projectname' do
 >    config = use_native_modules!
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Executing `pod install --verbose` command provided the following details:

> /Users/username/Documents/projectname/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js
> error Failed to build the app: No package name found. We couldn't
> parse the namespace from neither your build.gradle[.kts] file at
> /Users/username/Documents/projectname/android/app/build.gradle nor your
> package in the AndroidManifest at
> /Users/username/Documents/projectname/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.

During RN update I followed [react native upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper) instructions which guided me to remove `package="my.app.bundle.android"` property out of `manifest` object in `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file. Putting it back solved my issue.

Comment: I faced the same problem. The solution was to use the correct node version in the react-native project. In my case it was Node 18. You have to check with exact version of RN are you using and which is the matching NodeJS version. I would bet on the latest Node LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use yarn install. Thats what worked for me...

- Go to main folder
- Delete nodes folder
- Run `sudo npm install` or just `npm install`
- `cd ios`
- `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

Having same issue while building app on AppCenter, locally works perfectly

Is there any possibility to track this error? Cause I've seen that there can be a lof of reasons why I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Easily:

1. Run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` in the `root` of your `React Native` project.
2. In the `ios` folder run `pod install`.

**Edit:**

No hacks with any of:

- `@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios`
- `require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'`
- `require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'`

were needed.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow :

1. npm install
2. npm install -g react-native-cli
3. go to your ios folder -> cd ios
4. pod install

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have a newer version of Node. When I ran `expo run:ios`, I got the error from the question, but no useful debug information. But, when I did

```
$ cd ios
$ pod install
```

I got the error:

```
React Native needs Node.js >= 16. You're currently on version v15.14.0. Please upgrade Node.js to a supported version and try again.
```

After switching to a newer node with

```
$ nvm use 20
```

it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

After removing several react-native npm packages (ie: react-native-bluetooth-serial, react-native-sound, and more...) `pod install` works.

It appears the pod install error is related to older react-native packages that don't support cocoa pods? I'm not sure the details but removing those packages from node_modules & package.json solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that:

```
use_native_modules!
```

is unsupported by earlier versions of CocoaPods. For example, our install was the app downloaded from the [CocaoPods website](https://cocoapods.org/app). That version is `1.5.2`.

Run:

```
pod --version
```

to check which version. If need be, uninstall and then re-install but in Terminal by running:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

At least as of late October 2019, the current gem version available is `1.8.4`. Once successfully installed, re-attempt the `pod install` and hopefully all is well.

Comment: downvotes are fine but it would be polite to offer some explanation? I can then attempt to improve the answer or remove it entirely.

Comment: Tested with 1.8.4 - clearly not caused by cocoapods version. Your build is nondeterministic. You had to change something else while upgrading or just assumed that "it just works!" with this version.

Comment: @twboc if you think it unrelated to cocoapods version you would have been unable to reproduce the error on both 1.5.2 and 1.8.4. Did you try 1.5.2?

Comment: OK but to be sure you need to try 1.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after I tried to `react-native run-ios` an Expo app. The error I got indicated that something was wrong with the Pods, so I ran `cd ios && pod install`, which is how I got a similar error as the OP.

In that case, you obviously need to `expo start` instead of `react-native run-ios`.

Answer (score 0):

This started happening out of the blue today, and the problem was a space in my directory structure. Ex:

/path/to/Directory\ Name/RNProject throws the !native_modules error
/path/to/DirectoryName/RNProject works as it should

Pods was looking for "Directory. "

Answer (score 0):

maybe its related to rights issues

adding  "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "3.0.0" in package.json

and

sudo chown -R user .

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to switch to a newer version of node.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete Podfile.lock works. if you are facing issue even after all the answers. –

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this ios/chefzone.xcodeproj exists. In my case, this folder was deleted. then

yarn install,
pod install,
run it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above didn't work for me. I had to **restart my mac** and then pod install worked, without changing anything else.

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons may be outdated version of Ruby. Use following command to upgrade it.

```
rvm install 2.6.1
rvm use 2.6.1 --default
```

Or you can follow below article, which has a detailed explanation of upgrading ruby and associated gems.

https://help.learn.co/en/articles/2789231-how-to-upgrade-from-ruby-2-3-to-2-6

Comment: I was using an old version fo node

Answer (score -1):

Does anyone have a consistently recreatable solution for this issue that does not revolve around getting rid of use_native_modules? I have looked into:

- Changing Ruby Version
- Changing CocoaPods version
- Invalidating NPM and Cocoapods cache

And I am unable to fix the issue. It appears to be some npm dependency, but others on my team are not seeing it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: If the answers here do not solve your issue, please create a new question. Give a link to this Q&A, and explain what you have tried, and what happened. You will need to give more details: the complete error message, your podfile, and your package.json (because Cory Robinson's answer says he fixed by removing some older packages from his package.json). And of course delete any cache folders or lock files.

Answer (score -2):

Getting rid of the line `use_native_modules!` works as well. Maybe this has been deprecated or syntax has changed? Curious to hear from others.

Update: Seems to be an issue with react-native 0.60.0. Until a release fixes this bug, 0.59.10 can be explicitly installed, and you only need to add CocoaPods as necessary.

`react-native init APP_NAME --version react-native@0.59.10`

Answer (score -3):

Go to this repository :`ProjectName -> ios -> Podfile`

1. In the `Podfile`, delete   `use_native_modules`!
2. Execute again pod install
3. Enjoy your new pod

Comment: Useless, while we delete use_native_modules then it's not install native dependancies ...