# React Native - iOS - Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have just started out with React Native. I was following the React Native CLI Quickstart from the official documentation. That does also mean I am up to date with React Native version **0.61.2**.

Since then I have done some basic UI, checking with the result in the iPhone simulator. It works when running `react-native run-ios`, not really touching the *ios/Podfile* too much.

My problem is running *pod install* inside my *ios/* folder always results in an error! This becomes a problem now where I need to install additional packages. But it is already failing with default Podfile!

**Error message:**

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass.

 #  from /Users/marcel/Projekte/WerBinIch/ios/Podfile:43
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    use_native_modules!
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

**ios/Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'WerBinIch' do
  # Pods for WerBinIch
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'


  target 'WerBinIchTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end
```

I have no idea how to deal with this! I have no idea how the Podfile and the thing with the xcode files really work! I was trying to delete folders accomplishing a reset. More than that I have no idea what the error message could mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-native ios Podfile issue with "use\_native\_modules!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917963/react-native-ios-podfile-issue-with-use-native-modules)

Comment: Thank you! The answer on that thread helped. I needed to install the npm package @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios.

Comment: I upgraded 0.72 -> 0.73 and many packages so not exactly sure what changed but I get this error now every time I run `yarn install` or `pod install`, I have to **delete yarn.lock** each time and then it works (until I have to run it again)

Answer (score 11):

This error happens when you cd to ios folder and run "pod install"
and is because you added a new react native module by

npm -i *package*

instead of using yarn

yarn add *package*

To solve this problem, just go to the main react native project folder where package.json is and run the command below again

yarn cache clean

yarn add *package*

Then try cd to the ios folder and run "pod install" and there will no more errors. Hope this can help the other people who are also facing the same problem.

Comment: You are a savior.

Comment: I am not using yarn, just npm

Comment: @AbdulBasit sorry for late. You should delete the whole node_modules, Pods folder in ios folder, Podfile.lock and do "yarn" followed by 'cd ios', then 'pod install'. This is like cleaning everything and reinstall all modules and pods from scratch. Make sure you do not mix yarn and npm commands. Just use yarn, is easier and save the headache.

Comment: I don't use `yarn`, never did, I use `npm`

Answer (score 7):

This answer solve my problem well :

[react-native ios Podfile issue with "use_native_modules!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917963/react-native-ios-podfile-issue-with-use-native-modules)

Here is the correct answer:

1 - Your `Podfile` should contain this line on top

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
```

2 - Make sure your package.json and node_module folders has this module installed

```
@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios
```

3 - If you didn't find after you run `yarn install` - means you have old cache node_modules in your machine and you need to clean it before reinstalling the package again.

4 - Clean cache

```
$ yarn cache clean
```

*5 - Make sure you have this file `react-native.config.js` and its configuration is VALID - and it doesn't have non-existing NPM packages - this step is LAST AND MOSTLY THE CAUSE of the error*

Example of my `react-native.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/'],
  dependencies: {}, // make sure this deps are all valid installed packages or empty if you don't need it
};
```

6 - Install node packages `yarn install` and your pods should work now!
 `$ pod install --repo-update`

HAPPY coding!

Comment: Is it possible to not use require_relaitve "..." and instead use something like require_absolute "<GIT_URL_TO_A_REPO>"? I desperately need this as my projects are going to sit into two different places

Comment: Solved it for me

Answer (score 2):

after half of a day and try every solution, finally, I replace both

- `react-native`
- `@react-native-community`

folder from another RN 0.63 Project to node_modules and it's solved.
maybe my cache was not deleted or replaced correctly.

Comment: Only one that worked for me :exploding_head:

Answer (score 2):

In my case I accidentally created a package.json in my iOS folder. This seemed to confuse the react native build. I deleted the package.json in my ios folder, leaving the package.json in the root project folder and things worked.

Answer (score 2):

There can be another possible set up from the `Xcode command line tool`, which can fix `pod install`.
Try resetting it again as shown here[image]

Comment: Thanks, this has worked for me after uninstalling xcode beta and installing xcode just choose the command line tools with the same value again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, and I fixed this by installing the Xcode application.

Answer (score 0):

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `[]' for nil.

from .../Podfile:53

`config = use_native_modules!'// *issue is here*

I've also got above issue and this issue is in while doing pod install for existing iOS project which has react native setup.

***You can start from beginning to resolve this issue***

**Install Homebrew**

Execute below command in terminal :

1. /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
2. PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:${PATH}
   export PATH
3. (echo; echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /Users/lokeshvyas/.zprofile
4. eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
5. brew help
6. brew doctor

It should look like then everything is good. -> **Your system is ready to brew.**

**Install Yarn**

> Yarn.lock and node_modules delete from root folder and from iOS
> folder. If already exist.

yarn install     (In terminal on root folder)

Install Cocoapods

1. brew install cocoapods
2. pod setup
3. pod init
4. pod install

Answer (score -1):

- Add
  `"@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "3.0.0"` into your package.json file and run `npm install` in your main directory
- Then `cd ios` and run `pod install`

Comment: Dont know why you are being downvoted, this solved my problem. Sure I might bump into something else now but the other answers did not work.