# Can't run react native project for ios

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I am developing react native app and i am new in react-native, firstly I have worked for android platform and successfully build apk file.
Now i want to run it for ios version with the command **react-native run-ios** from my mackbook but it's throws an error:

note: from starting i have developed this app on macbook

```
user-MacBook-Pro:myApp user$ react-native run-ios
error Cannot read property 'podfile' of null. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'podfile' of null
    at warnAboutPodInstall (/Users/user/project/myApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/link/warnAboutPodInstall.js:43:90)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (Users/user/project/myApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:80:36)
    at Command.handleAction (Users/user/project/myApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:164:23)
    at Command.listener (Users/user/project/myApp/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Command.parseArgs (Users/user/project/myApp/node_modules/commander/index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (Users/user/project/myApp/node_modules/commander/index.js:474:21)
    at setupAndRun (Users/user/project/myApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:237:24)
    at Object.run (Users/user/project/myApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:184:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:117:7)
```

Podfile

```
 platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

 target 'myApp' do
  # Pods for myApp
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'myAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'myApp-tvOS' do
  # Pods for myApp-tvOS

  target 'myApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

please help me who knows the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Terminal
2. Move **ios** folder under React-Native project
3. Run **pod install** command - This will install all linked libraries for the installed rpm modules that require linking.
4. After that run react-native run-ios **or** Double click on the    projectName.xcworkspace, this will open the Xcode.
5. Select device to run and play the project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :
when run the command pod install from ios directory
this happens..


    user-MacBook-Pro:ios user$ pod install

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass.

 #  from /Users/user/project/myApp/ios/Podfile:42
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    use_native_modules!
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------

Comment: Please refer:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423002/react-native-ios-invalid-podfile-file-undefined-method-for-nilnilcl & https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/860

Answer (score 1):

- First of all you need to know the basics of React Native. You can view official instructions of how to run React Native project on device from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)
- But before running application on iOS you need to do some additional things

---

- Navigate into **ios** folder inside your root folder of project
- Open terminal from active location and run this command

> pod install

- If you need to more about cocoapods visit [this](https://cocoapods.org/)
- After that open XCODE and navigate into **ios** folder and open your project file with the extension with .xcworkspace

> MyProject.xcworkspace

- Now you can run your iOS application via XCODE but before running application make sure you have clean your build folder **( Command+Shift+K )** and rebuild **( Command+B )** the project using XCODE.
- Finally choose the device and run your application from XCODE. **( Command+R )**

Comment: Thanks for your answer :
when run the command pod install from ios directory
this error occurs->

user-MacBook-Pro:ios user$ pod install

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass.

 #  from /Users/user/project/myApp/ios/Podfile:42
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    use_native_modules!
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------

Comment: @BellalHossain see this issue -> https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/860

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, from your toplevel project directory run these commands:

```sh
cd ios # <-- To get into your ios subdirectory
ls
```

You should see a file named "Podfile" like shown here:

```
drwxr-xr-x   8 r  staff    256 Sep 21 14:04 AwesomeTSProject
-rw-r--r--   1 r  staff    749 Sep 21 14:04 Podfile
```

Next run the following command:

```
pod install
```

You should see files like these created:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 r  staff    128 Sep 21 14:04 AwesomeTSProjectTests
drwxr-xr-x@  5 r  staff    160 Sep 21 14:22 AwesomeTSProject.xcworkspace
drwxr-xr-x  10 r  staff    320 Sep 29 10:00 .
drwxr-xr-x@  4 r  staff    128 Sep 29 10:19 AwesomeTSProject.xcodeproj
-rw-r--r--   1 r  staff  19077 Sep 29 10:19 Podfile.lock
-rw-r--r--@  1 r  staff   6148 Sep 30 04:00 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  26 r  staff    832 Jan  9 09:01 Pods
drwxr-xr-x  25 r  staff    800 Jan  9 09:42 ..
```

As long as you don't see any errors, you can now run the following commands:

```
cd ..
```

You should be popped up out of the ios folder and moved up to your parent project directory.

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

If all goes well, you should see an iOS simulator with your App.