# React Native Pod Error - [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 767: unexpected token at ''. | Related Issue #448

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, react-native-cli

I have already tried : [#448](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/448)

**Environment**

```
System:
OS: macOS 10.15
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4250U CPU @ 1.30GHz
Memory: 30.63 MB / 4.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/sh
Binaries:
Node: 10.15.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.19.2 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.13.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
IDEs:
Xcode: 11.2.1/11B500 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
```

**Description**

[image]

```
➜ ios git:(master) ✗ pod install --verbose
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/jack/Desktop/root in PATH, mode 040777

[!] Invalid Podfile file: 767: unexpected token at ''.

from /Users/jack/Desktop/root/outonox/quibik/ios/Podfile:45
use_native_modules!
end

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:301:in rescue in block in from_ruby' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:295:in block in from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in instance_eval' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:293:in new' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:293:in from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:259:in from_file' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:200:in podfile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:150:in verify_podfile_exists!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in <top (required)>' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `
```

'
**Reproducible Demo**

Not sure why this is happing, but this is started after installing "@react-native-firebase" this package

**POD FILE**

> platform :ios, '9.0' require_relative
>   '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
>
> target 'quibik' do   # Pods for quibik
>
> pod 'RNFBAuth', :path =>
>   "../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth"   pod 'RNFBApp', :path
>   => "../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app"
>
> pod 'FBLazyVector', :path =>
>   "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"   pod
>   'FBReactNativeSpec', :path =>
>   "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"   pod
>   'RCTRequired', :path =>
>   "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"   pod
>   'RCTTypeSafety', :path =>
>   "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"   pod 'React',
>   :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'   pod 'React-Core', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/'   pod 'React-CoreModules', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'   pod
>   'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
>   pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'   pod
>   'React-RCTAnimation', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'   pod
>   'React-RCTBlob', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'   pod 'React-RCTImage',
>   :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'   pod
>   'React-RCTLinking', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'   pod
>   'React-RCTNetwork', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'   pod
>   'React-RCTSettings', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'   pod
>   'React-RCTText', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'   pod
>   'React-RCTVibration', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'   pod
>   'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
>
> pod 'React-cxxreact', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'   pod 'React-jsi',
>   :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'   pod
>   'React-jsiexecutor', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'   pod
>   'React-jsinspector', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'   pod
>   'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path =>
>   "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"   pod
>   'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path =>
>   "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"   pod 'Yoga', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
>
> pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
>   pod 'glog', :podspec =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'   pod
>   'Folly', :podspec =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
>
> pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path =>
>   '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'
>
> target 'quibikTests' do
>       inherit! :search_paths
>       # Pods for testing   end
>
> use_native_modules! end
>
> target 'quibik-tvOS' do   # Pods for quibik-tvOS
>
> target 'quibik-tvOSTests' do
>       inherit! :search_paths
>       # Pods for testing   end
>
> end

Comment: Can you post your `Podfile` here?

Comment: thanks for prompt reply... i have added pod file in Github. https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/885

Comment: Take a look on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57239476/2638849. Maybe your solution has there

Comment: I was stuck on this exact error for about 2 days, it started for me after installing rvm, so at least in my case it appears to have been a problem with the ruby version. I encountered issues with version 2.6.3 and with the default mac version of 2.3.7. The problem stopped after cleaning rvm installation and re installing. I noticed the file worked fine on a coworker's machine running rvm with ruby 2.5.3 as default and cocoapods 1.8.4, after reinstalling rvm and emulating this environment the file worked again on my machine. Hope it helps.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution so I had to move my code to a new solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.

```
rm -rf package-lock.json
cd ios
pod install
```

Comment: This issue is already resolved and your answer is nearly correct. I will accept.

Comment: Can you also add what solved issue for you?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is:

- Install Yarn Package manager

> `npm install --global yarn`

- In order to not to mix package managers

> `rm package-lock.json`

- Then run;

> `yarn install`

> `cd ios && pod install && cd ..`

> `npx react-native run-ios`

Good luck!