# i can't run pod install with react native

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I have created a mobile app with react-native but when I run `pod install` in ios directory, getting the following error.

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!.



#  from /Users/softcity/AppTest/ios/Podfile:42
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    end
 >  use_native_modules!
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------
SoftCitys-MacBook-Air:ios softcity$
```

Here is the code of Podfile:

```
 platform :ios, '9.0'
    require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'    
    target 'AppTest' do
      # Pods for AppTest
      pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
      pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
      pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
      pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
      pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
      pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
      pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
      pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
      pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
      pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
      pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
      pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
      pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
      pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
      pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
      pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
      pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
      pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

      pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
      pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
      pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
      pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
      pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
      pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
      pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

      pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
      pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
      pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

      target 'AppTestTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
      end
    use_native_modules!
    end

    target 'AppTest-tvOS' do
      # Pods for AppTest-tvOS

      target 'AppTest-tvOSTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
      end

    end
```

*Please help me !!*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917963/react-native-ios-podfile-issue-with-use-native-modules

Comment: i try with this documentation but don't working

Comment: @nourhouda Have you found a solution?