# How can I solve this " Invalid `Podfile` " error?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm new to ios development and I got a zip file from another developer for an ios project. When I ran pod install, the terminal shows this error:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- /Users/abc/Desktop/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules.

 #  from /Users/abc/Desktop/ios/Podfile:2
 #  -----------------------------------------
 #  platform :ios, '9.0'
 >  require_relative '../node_modules/@react- 
 native-community/cli-platform- 
 ios/native_modules'
 #  
 #  -----------------------------------------
```

The directory is like this 
~/Desktop/ios 
ls

```
GoogleService-Info.plist ISApp.xcodeproj          
Podfile.lock
ISApp                    ISApp.xcworkspace        
Pods
ISApp-tvOS               ISAppTests               
instrumentscli0.trace
ISApp-tvOSTests          Podfile
```

I have looked at the thread below but it doesn't help at all. Any input is appreciated. 
[react-native ios Podfile issue with "use_native_modules!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917963/react-native-ios-podfile-issue-with-use-native-modules)

Comment: I think this could answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917963/react-native-ios-podfile-issue-with-use-native-modules

Comment: I already looked at the post before asking the question. However, I'm stuck at step 2. I tried install package.js, cli-platform-ios/native_modules, and ran yarn install but the error is still there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the contents of your podfile. Your podfile is probably not formatted correctly. If it is, one workaround could be to move your podfile to a different location, uninstall and reinstall cocoapods (`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` and `sudo gem install cocoapods`), initialize pod (`pod init`), copy the content of your podfile (making sure the formatting is not messed up) to the new podfile and then install pod again (`pod install`).