# Podfile install failed - Can't find node modules

Tags: react-native, expo, cocoapods

```
Command `pod install` failed. 
 └─ Cause: Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- ./scripts/autolinking.

 #  from /Users/developer/Documents/Project1/ios/Podfile:1
-------------------------------------------
 >  require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")  
 #  require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")  
-------------------------------------------

sh: node: command not found
```

I've been trying to figure this out all day and still can't figure out what the issue is. I've got `node` in my paths so it can find the command.

I figured out if I were to change the first require line to `File.join('node_modules/expo/scripts/autolinking')` it manages to execute, however then it throws the same issue for a file within the node modules, which i can't go through and change all the node_modules manually.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567934/6918604 Might help?

Answer (score 0):

On Mac M1
Install CocoaPod from HomeBrew to your terminal in the project folder or globally
Delete existing Podfile if any .
If none, good dont worry

run `pod init`

This will create a new Podfile

Then in ios folder run `pod install` or `npx pod-install`

if you get errors below, you probably have wrong `.env`

```
ERROR: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"
ERROR: Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.`

Hope this helps :)
```