# 'Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager.' error in react native cli

Tags: reactjs, macos, react-native, npm, npm-install

I keep getting RNSScreen error. I have followed all instructions on react-navigation guide but nothing has worked for me.

Comment: Same for me even. Trying to create a tab app with react native cli(Strudy purpose). You got solution?

Answer (score 8):

Looks like native packages are not linked automatically. So try this

> **Note**: In your case it can be `'../'` instead of `'../../../'` because I am using Monorepo.

### Podfile

```rb
pod 'RNScreens', :path => '../../../node_modules/react-native-screens/'
pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../../../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/'
pod 'react-native-safe-area-context', :path => '../../../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/'
```

Then Install pods

```sh
yarn podinstall
```

Then terminate already running MetroBundler terminal.
And, build app again

```sh
yarn ios
```

---

### Working Example

```js
/**
 * @format
 */
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

import SplashScreen from '../common/src/containers/splashScreen';
import LoginScreen from '../common/src/containers/loginScreen';
import LoginOTPScreen from '../common/src/containers/loginOTPScreen';
import SearchScreen from './src/searchScreen';

import React from 'react';
import {name as appName, displayName} from './app.json';
import {Provider as PaperProvider} from 'react-native-paper';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import {enableScreens} from 'react-native-screens';
enableScreens();

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const App = () => {
  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashScreen">
          <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="LoginOTPScreen" component={LoginOTPScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="SearchScreen" component={SearchScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

> Make sure `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` is the **top**

Comment: Please Don't forget to remove the ios/build an app on the ios simulator then try it !

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To enable auto-linking, it was important to have used
`import {enableScreens} from 'react-native-screens'; enableScreens();`
in the code for `"react-native-screens": "*"` to appear.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are getting this error when working in a monorepo (@nrwl/nx for me), this solution worked for me.

https://github.com/nrwl/nx-react-native/issues/98#issuecomment-995299032

Adding the following packages in the app's package.json (not the workspace root's package.json) has solved the problem for both iOS and Android.

```
"@react-navigation/native": "*",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "*",
"react-native-screens": "*",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "*"
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I ended up adding it to both package jsons. Not 100% why, but this seems incorrect in the monorepo.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error and was doing `expo start --dev-client` and when I just did `expo start` it works.

Answer (score 1):

There were many answers that didn't work for me.
Finally I found this was related to react-native-screens package configuration.

On iOS obtaining current device orientation requires asking the system to generate orientation notifications. Our library uses them to enforce correct interface orientation when navigating between screens. To make sure that there are no issues with screen orientation you should put following code in your AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ... 
#if !TARGET_OS_TV
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
#endif // !TARGET_OS_TV
    ...
    return YES:
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
#if !TARGET_OS_TV
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
#endif // !TARGET_OS_TV
}
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-screens

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps

- First stop the metro
- Delete the "node_modules" folder
- Run below commands respectively

  npm install, npx react-native start, npx react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using nx (https://nx.dev/). My solution is:

Adding the following packages in the app's package.json (not the workspace root's package.json) has solved the problem for both iOS and Android.

```
"@react-navigation/native": "*",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "*",
"react-native-screens": "*",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "*",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "*"
```

More about:
https://github.com/nrwl/nx-react-native/issues/98#issuecomment-995299032

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nx expo, you should be to intall libraries using:

```
nx run <APP_NAME>:install react-native-safe-area-context
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused while installing the react-native-screens package. Try to install its **3.18.0** version and it will work.

If you still have issues, delete node_modules and package-lock.json file, run **npm cache clean --force** and then reinstall all packages and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

When navigation packages are added without pausing the running build, this happens. Make sure to stop the iOS or Android process, install the packages, and integrate the routing afterward.

This worked for me you can try this.