# requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found on the UIManager

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to make an app with React Native and I've been stuck for hours. Whenever I try to run my app with Android Studio I get the error: "requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found on the UIManager". I think I have all the dependencies needed to get NativeModules, here I have all the package.json dependencies:

```
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
"firebase": "^9.1.3",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-global-hook": "^2.0.0",
"react-native": "0.66.0",
"react-native-ble-manager": "^7.6.3",
"react-native-ble-plx": "^2.0.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.3",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
"react-native-screens": "^3.8.0",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
```

Is there anything else I need to install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66921263/invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rnsscreen-was-not-found-in-the-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Generally this means that `react-native-screens` is not installed
Try `npm i react-native-screens`, but I suggest trying whit the expo managed environment.