# How to fix React native app stopped working on android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webrtc

i added firebase to my react native project and it's stopped running on my emulator. I've had this issue with firebase & react-native some years back, don't know what the fix was.

Running adb logcat displays this

```
04-24 22:13:32.453   371   394 E system_server: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
04-24 22:13:32.465   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.468   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.471   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.476   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.479   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.480   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.482   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.484   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.485   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.486   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.487   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.488   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.493   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.494  4759  4759 E com.mvmarket: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
04-24 22:13:32.494   371   398 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
04-24 22:13:32.748   174  4798 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (101, <unspecified>/0)
04-24 22:13:32.755   202   271 E SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-24 22:13:32.755   202   271 E SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mvmarket, PID: 4759
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method createEgl14([I)Lorg/webrtc/EglBase14; in class Lorg/webrtc/EglBase; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.webrtc.EglBase' appears in /data/app/com.mvmarket-R-KOl49no3K6lCqfeV5j9A==/base.apk)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.oney.WebRTCModule.EglUtils.getRootEglBase(EglUtils.java:35)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.oney.WebRTCModule.EglUtils.getRootEglBaseContext(EglUtils.java:62)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.oney.WebRTCModule.WebRTCModule.<init>(WebRTCModule.java:107)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.oney.WebRTCModule.WebRTCModule.<init>(WebRTCModule.java:76)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.oney.WebRTCModule.WebRTCModulePackage.createNativeModules(WebRTCModulePackage.java:15)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactPackageHelper.getNativeModuleIterator(ReactPackageHelper.java:42)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:42)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1476)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1447)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1341)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1200(ReactInstanceManager.java:138)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1111)
04-24 22:13:32.818  4759  4807 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
04-24 22:13:32.850   371   473 E InputDispatcher: channel '932d8ad com.mvmarket/com.mvmarket.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-24 22:13:32.857   202   202 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{82ce2ce token=Token{53e3bc9 ActivityRecord{127bfd0 u0 com.mvmarket/.MainActivity t75}}})/@0xafd9b7e - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
04-24 22:13:32.857   202   202 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{82ce2ce token=Token{53e3bc9 ActivityRecord{127bfd0 u0 com.mvmarket/.MainActivity t75}}})/@0xafd9b7e - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
04-24 22:13:32.874   202   202 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{82ce2ce token=Token{53e3bc9 ActivityRecord{127bfd0 u0 com.mvmarket/.MainActivity t75}}})/@0xafd9b7e - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
04-24 22:13:32.890   202   202 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{82ce2ce token=Token{53e3bc9 ActivityRecord{127bfd0 u0 com.mvmarket/.MainActivity t75}}})/@0xafd9b7e - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
04-24 22:13:32.906   202   202 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{82ce2ce token=Token{53e3bc9 ActivityRecord{127bfd0 u0 com.mvmarket/.MainActivity t75}}})/@0xafd9b7e - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
04-24 22:13:32.924   202   202 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{82ce2ce token=Token{53e3bc9 ActivityRecord{127bfd0 u0 com.mvmarket/.MainActivity t75}}})/@0xafd9b7e - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
04-24 22:13:32.940   202   202 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{82ce2ce token=Token{53e3bc9 ActivityRecord{127bfd0 u0 com.mvmarket/.MainActivity t75}}})/@0xafd9b7e - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
04-24 22:13:32.956   202   202 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{82ce2ce token=Token{53e3bc9 ActivityRecord{127bfd0 u0 com.mvmarket/.MainActivity t75}}})/@0xafd9b7e - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
04-24 22:13:32.974   202   202 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{82ce2ce token=Token{53e3bc9 ActivityRecord{127bfd0 u0 com.mvmarket/.MainActivity t75}}})/@0xafd9b7e - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
04-24 22:13:32.990   202   202 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{82ce2ce token=Token{53e3bc9 ActivityRecord{127bfd0 u0 com.mvmarket/.MainActivity t75}}})/@0xafd9b7e - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
```

Comment: You've given us no errors, no stack traces, and didn't even explain how it stopped running and what happened instead.  How do you expect us to be able to help?  We have literally no useful information.

Comment: Added result from running `adb logcat` it now. i tried adding the logcat at first, but the question didnt pass cause "post is mostly code". There's no error. build is successful, just when the app tries launching, android alerts pops up saying "app keeps stopping" thanks. Was hoping else has faced the issue @GabeSechan

Comment: When you get that error, there's ALWAYS a stack trace in logcat.  Give us that.  What you gave us in your edit doesn't have it, its totally irrelevant.

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan .Edited again. Please check, thank you for your contribution so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it
According to the stacktrace, it was an issue with react-native-webrtc

Fixed with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67592188/11901942

Thanks @Gabe Sechan