# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager. [EXPO]

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, expo, expo-dev-client

After installing the **'dev-client'** and initiating the app with '**npx expo start --dev-client**' I encountered the following issue:

> Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "**RNSScreen**" was not found in the UIManager.

Prior to this, everything was functioning perfectly.

I'm working on incorporating Google authentication through Firebase into my Expo app.

This error is located at:
in RNSScreen (`at createAnimatedComponent.js:54`)
in Unknown (`at src/index.native.tsx:314`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66921263/invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rnsscreen-was-not-found-in-the-ui)